# How to bind implicit constructor/conversion in Python with pybind11?

Tags: python, c++, implicit-conversion, pybind11

I'm trying to mimic implicit conversion/construction of a simple struct in Python using `pybind11`:

```
struct MyType {
    double a;
    double b;
};

void func(size_t foo, const MyType& bar) {
    // ...
}

// ...


PYBIND11_MODULE(pymylib, module) {
    // ...
    py::class_< MyType >(module, "MyType")
        .def(py::init< double, double >(), "a"_a, "b"_a)
        .def(py::init([](const std::array< double, 2 >& ab){ return MyType({ab[0], ab[1]}); }), "ab"_a = std::array< double, 2>{ 1.0, 0.25 })   // not implicit
        .def_readwrite("a", &MyType::a)
        .def_readwrite("b", &MyType::b);

    py::implicitly_convertible< std::array< double, 2 >, MyType >();   // conversion is not implicit

    module.def("func", &func, "foo"_a, "bar"_a);
}
```

While in C++ one can use brace initialization `{}` without having to implicitly call `MyType` constructor (simplifying the syntax), I am still unable to have an implicit conversion from a list object when passing MyType as argument to `func`:

```
obj = module.MyType(8.7, 5.6)

module.func(47, obj)                        # works
module.func(47, module.MyType([4.1, 7.8]))  # works
module.func(47, [4.1, 7.8])                 # does not work ('incompatible function arguments')
```

From what I understand from [`pybind11` documentation](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/classes.html#brace-initialization), the constructor declaration `py::init< double, double >()` should bind brace-initialization implicitly, but it's not working as I expected:

```
TypeError: func(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. module.func(a: float, b: module.MyType)
```

I tried adding a custom constructor accepting a list/array, but it is still not called implicitly.

Due to the simplicity of the struct, having to explicitly call the constructor seems unnecessary, particularly if defined in a Python submodule or nested on another class;
How - if possible - do I achieve this behavior in Python?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your use case. Why are you initializing from std::array? That has nothing to do with implicit/ brace init

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Comment: @haleyk just an attempt to get it working, pybind11 already handles conversion from lists to STL types automatically, so I thought declaring a 'custom' constructor that wraps the brace initializer from an array would get me implicit construction

Comment: @kiner_shah updated the question with the full error message. It's not particularly informative, hence why I didn't bother initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you are citing refers to the way the python initializer calls the C++ constructor. It makes no remark as far as I can tell regarding implicit conversion from `list`. As you suspected, you need to register a special `py::init()` for it.

Now regarding why your special `py::init()` does not work: My best guess is you are missing `#include <pybind11/stl.h>`, see https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/stl.html:

> When including the additional header file `pybind11/stl.h`, conversions between `std::vector<>`/`std::deque<>`/`std::list<>`/`std::array<>`/`std::valarray<>`, `std::set<>`/`std::unordered_set<>`, and `std::map<>`/`std::unordered_map<>` and the Python `list`, `set` and `dict` data structures are automatically enabled. The types `std::pair<>` and `std::tuple<>` are already supported out of the box with just the core `pybind11/pybind11.h` header.

Here is a working demo: https://godbolt.org/z/WrPrb8cM8

Comment: Actually, I already had those headers included; the issue is caused by something else. While your working example does work, I found some issues when adding some complexity (inheritance, multiple implicit conversions), check [here](https://godbolt.org/z/3efMxdj43) what I mean.

Comment: There you go: https://godbolt.org/z/nnGG8x89q. In short, change `func2(14, [34, 68])` to `func2(14., (34., 68.))`. Firstly, `std::pair` is paired with a python tuple not a python list. Secondly, you have implicit conversions from (pairs of) `double`, but you test your functions with (lists of) `int`, while you should use (tuples of) `float`. So in essence you are asking for two levels of argument conversion, first `int` to `double`, then double to `First`. This is not possible in C++ and I suspect it is not possible in pybind either.

Comment: Indeed value data type is something I was not even considering, and what I was doing wrong. Those lists were leftover from my initial snippet in the OG question where `std::array` was being used; although I believe pybind11 already handles conversion between list and tuple implicitly (e.g. that code works with both `[]` and `()`). Regarding the data type, for `First` I can just add `py::implicitly_convertible< int, First >();` and it will account for both cases, for `Second` I'd need multiple variations, which isn't ideal.